# Corrupt Background

Tags: lubuntu, desktop-background

I am using Lubuntu 20.04. One day I found that my background was no longer an image, but instead, it took on whatever was previously sitting there on the screen. I tried to set a new background, but I cannot. There are no icons on the homepage. When I right-click I get an unusual drop-down box. I cannot view documents with the "file-manager" application, but I can view them with the "Document Viewer" application.

I installed gnome-tweak because I read that changing the background with that tool could help, but it too cannot change the background. I can select a new image as my background with the tool, but it does not make the background the selected image.

I have included an image to help clarify what I am talking about. Please let me know if I need to clarify my question or provide more information.

[image of corrupt background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kIke.jpg)

Best,
Gabriel

Comment: Your problem goes far beyond a "corrupt background" and installing stuff just to change the background, something that you should be able to do *without* any special tool can only make things worse.

Comment: Try a live session and if the problem *doesn't* persist consider reinstalling. If it does than you have an hardware problem.

Comment: gnome-tweak won't work because Lubuntu does not use a gnome desktop

Comment: Are you sure you're using a Lubuntu/LXQt session? and haven't logged into an non-Lubuntu session?  Changing the wallpaper is done just like the manual says - https://manual.lubuntu.me/lts/3/3.2/3.2.5/desktop.html?highlight=wallpaper HOWEVER that assumes you're using the Lubuntu session, and didn't login with LXQt (*will be identical for many functions but it's upstream LXQt & not all Lubuntu scripts will work*) or an `openbox` session (where Lubuntu/LXQt things won't function; screen would look like yours though without LXQt panel at bottom usually unless you forced that to start)

Comment: Thank you all for your comments.

I would be surprised if my computer's hardware caused this error because I had no trouble changing the desktop wallpaper for a long time. However, if I cannot solve it I will assume that the hardware must be the issue.

I forgot that Lubuntu uses LXQt and not gnome (I think I have that straight). Thank you for that correction, I will keep it in mind.

I only have installed and used Lubunu on this computer. I tried to change the wallpaper by going to preferences -> LXQt settings -> Desktop, but the Desktop button does nothing.

Comment: Yes you issue reminds me of a bug (maybe bugs) which occurs when a user makes an incorrect setting.. The easiest fix is to revert whatever change was made in the session before the issue occurred.. If you have multiple screens it maybe https://bugs.launchpad.net/openbox/+bug/1845756 but one issue I recall was Qt5 related (*not an issue in later releases beyond 20.04*) as well as https://github.com/lxqt/lxqt/issues/1925 https://github.com/lxqt/pcmanfm-qt/issues/1033 & more.

Comment: You could try switching from `openbox` to another WM (https://manual.lubuntu.me/lts/3/3.2/3.2.13/session_settings.html for now) eg. `xfwm4` for example is what Debian uses but I test with `fluxbox` & more  after which a logout/login will be required; if it's an `openbox` issue it'll be gone.. You don't mention multiple monitors as most openbox issues occur with multiple in specific orientations only. I'd still check session (`openbox` has no wallpaper by default) and openbox's menu is very different to LXQt's; where no wallpaper/non-LXQt managed you get openbox's menu.

Comment: Hello! I only have one monitor. I have swapped my WM to fluxbox and the background problem is mostly fixed. The screen no longer grabs whatever was there, but I am still unable to set a background. That I cannot set a background as an image is okay. It seems that you hit the nail on the head and the bug was with openbox! Do you know of any WMs that are very similar to openbox? I have tried a few and they have been quite different. If you do not have any off hand, that is okay, I will search. Thank you very much for all your help @guiverc !

Comment: You're using *focal* (20.04) which has some bugs in the Qt5 libs that impact some screen orientations (*fixed in later releases but as not security related; not backported to Qt5 used by 20.04 LTS*) but on a single screen I'd not expect them impacting you. As for WM's I test 5+ (inc. `openbox`) with Lubuntu/LXQt but I have no favorite; I'd likely use `xfwm4` as it's what Debian defaults too & other reasons (`openbox` is a Lubuntu choice; many team members love it)   Openbox has some issues that can impact occasional users; your 20.04 has some issues that didn't exist in newer Qt5 & LXQt too.

Comment: I'd likely have asked your question on Lubuntu's discourse/forum; it's not a Q&A site (like this is) & allows discussion (*comments I'm making which are really off-topic here*!) and you may have got some *dev* responses I can't give.  If you make certain config changes incorrectly you can get what you describe; undoing the changes made will resolve it, but the issues as I recall all related to the *focal* software stack (20.04) which was 5 releases ago for me & *long ago*. I'm about to do a *focal* QA-test (20.04.5) but that's install only as focus now is all *kinetic* (LXQt 1.1) & *jammy* bp

Comment: Oops! You are right, I should not have asked such an open-ended question here. I shall try not to do that again. However, thank you for your recommendation, @guiverc. The information you have provided has helped solve my problem.

Comment: If it solved your problem, please write up how you solved it as an answer here; you can accept it and gain some *rep* for this site. You're welcome to use anything I provided; even reference the comments - but answer with what you did etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My above problem had to do with a bug with the Openbox Window Manager (window manager is abbreviated WM). By installing a new WM I was able to fix the freaky background problem, but I am still not able to change the background image or color.

My solution:

1. Research and select desired WM to replace OpenBox
2. Open the terminal
3. Type: `sudo apt install [NAME OF WM]`
4. Open Application Menu -> Preferences -> LXQt settings -> Session Settings
5. Change the Window Manager by clicking the drop-down menu and selecting the desired WM
6. Restart your computer

Best, gabriels